# What's the best way to say "redesign" pertaining to a web page/site?

Tags: word-choice, words, terminology, computing

I want to say that I'm "redesigning" a web page, and I can think of several words that may fit, but I'm not sure which is most appropriate or most widely-accepted in the technology world.

- 更新　→　This is usually used for upgrading/updating of software, although I have seen it used to mean "refresh" (for a view of some sort; browser, file manager, etc.).  I'm not really upgrading anything in the sense of new functionality, simply a visual redesign (although I suppose that implies even a miniscule amount of functional improvement).
- 改築　→　Rebuilding or reconstructing; I'm not sure if it can be used figuratively for something not physical/structural.
- 改造　→　Remodeling; same argument as previous.
- 改装　→　Remodeling/redecorating; same as previous; seen it mostly used for redecorating the inside of buildings, houses, etc.
- 改善・改良　→　Straightforward "improvement"

So is one of these (or other) the "set" term for "redesign" in the tech world?  My gut tells me it is probably 更新 even though that one makes the least semantic sense in my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's chiefly a "visual redesign", I'd say デザインを新しくします（しました）。("We'll have/We've got a new design!")

- 更新: It'll mean "update" of website, like adding a new article on WordPress. Maybe デザインの更新 would get your meaning across. The "refresh" sense is limited to browser function.
- 改築: It sounds like you revamp the site's structure, or something.
- 改造: Same as above, just more radically :)
- 改装: This could be the best one word among these words.
- 改善・改良: They only mean "improvement", as you said.

There's another widely used word: リニューアル (as noun *or verb*). Perhaps this would convey more "refresh" vibe.

Comment: So which one do you think is better or more common:  新しくする or 改装?

Comment: Obviously I'm too late, and the answer is: both are OK, I don't find gap in frequency between them.